# intellisense with VS code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

i'm using VS Code but Intellisense doesn't work with C# then in Javascript it's Ok. 
C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) extension is installed

can you help me please?

thanks

features:
VS code: 1.13
Window 7 professionnel pack 1

Comment: Close and open your visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Save your file with the .cs extention. (file_name.cs)

Comment: Hello, the file is already .cs extension. The intellisense list only all object declared in the file but don't know all property and method of this object.

Comment: can you post the code and show what intellisense you expect, also read the docs on working with c# :https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

Comment: Hello,

I've declared a variable 'User' of object 'APSUser'. Intellisense show a list that contain objects and properties but don't those of my Object 'APSUer'.
This object is issue of a librairy that i've added on the top with instruction 'Using'

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the "Omnisharp log" in Output view. It will show you the progress in project loading and could give you a solution.

In my case intellisense was not working because the project load time (1 min. by default) was exceeded. Following Omnisharp log indications it was fixed adding the following setting:

"omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout": 120